# Android gradle apk splits, getting versionCode & versionName in code

Tags: android, gradle

We start splitting APKs to reduce APK size. And we cannot figure out why the `versionCode` we get in code (Java) is always the default one.

Here is the relevant gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId applicationIdPrefix
    versionCode 1000
    versionName "3.3.0"

// This is the configuration we want to publish
defaultPublishConfig "productionRelease"

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  def apkName = "$projectName-${variant.name}-v${versionString}.${baseVersionCode}.apk"

  variant.outputs.each { output ->
    // Redefine the versionCode and the apkName to include ABI when available
    def abiName = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
    def baseAbiVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(abiName)

    if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
      output.versionCodeOverride = variant.versionCode + baseAbiVersionCode
      output.versionNameOverride = "$versionString (${output.versionCodeOverride})"
```

And this is how to retrieve the `versionName` and `versionCode`:

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

They are always 3.3.0 and 1000. Why? We want to get these values because we want to display them under settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, changed to this and problem solved:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

---

This following does not gives us the correct version name and version code after we split our APK. I guess what happened is that that `BuildConfig.java` is generated during grade sync.

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

Maybe that’s why it is outdated and doesn’t match our actual version code, which was override with these 2 lines of gradle:

```
output.versionCodeOverride = variant.versionCode + baseAbiVersionCode
output.versionNameOverride = "$versionString (${output.versionCodeOverride})".
```